# iPython notebook won't convert to PDF when using align

Tags: python, pdf, latex, ipython

If I have an iPython notebook, and a cell contains an `align` statement, as in the following:

```
$$
\begin{align}
x &= 3 \\
y &= 4
\end{align}
$$
```

Then running `ipython nbconvert test.ipynb --to pdf` gives me the following error:

```
! Package amsmath Error: Erroneous nesting of equation structures;
(amsmath)                trying to recover with `aligned'.

See the amsmath package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.233 \end{align}

? 
! Emergency stop.
 ...                                              

l.233 \end{align}

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on notebook.log.
```

I can't find `notebook.log` anywhere. Where is it located, and, more importantly, why is align breaking my PDF conversion? I have `amsmath` installed!

Comment: Try removing the `$$`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@moose was right: you should have both the `$$ ... $$` and `align` notation combined. Pick one of the two.

That is, for multiline equations, use:

```
\begin{align}
x &= 3 \\
y &= 4
\end{align}
```

And for single-line equations, use:

```
$$
x = 3
$$
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you are missing an extra "&" in your
equation. Please try to change "&=" into "&=&". I assume that you want the equations on two separate lines aligned on the equals sign.

Comment: That's not correct – you're just adding another column by including that extra ampersand.